# Supremum with respect to one variable is continuous (proof verification)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

For some reason I do not feel this is correct. Can someone please verify?

> Let $X$ be compact and $Y \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be closed. Let $f\colon X\times Y\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function (under the product metric). Then, $y\mapsto\sup_{x\in X}f(x,y)$ is continuous.

*Proof:* Fix $y\in Y$ and $\epsilon>0$. Let $B(y)\subset Y$ be the unit ball around $y$. Since the restriction 
$$
f|_{X\times(\overline{B(y)} \cap Y) }
$$
 is uniformly continuous, we can find $0<\delta<1$ such that for all $(x_{1},y_{1}),(x_{2},y_{2})\in X\times(\overline{B(y)}\cap Y)$ satisfying $d((x_{1},y_{1}),(x_{2},y_{2}))<\delta$, $|f(x_{1},y_{1})-f(x_{2},y_{2})|<\epsilon$. Therefore, for $y^{\prime}\in\overline{B(y)}\cap Y$ such that $d(y,y^{\prime})<\delta$,
$$
|\sup_{x\in X}f(x,y)-\sup_{x\in X}f(x,y^{\prime})|\leq\sup_{x\in X}|f(x,y)-f(x,y^{\prime})|=|f(x^{\star},y)-f(x^{\star},y^{\prime})|<\epsilon.
$$

Comment: I think this is fine. Where do you feel that you are going wrong, if anywhere?

Comment: Thanks, @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг. I'm not sure where I would have gone wrong (if at all)... just a feeling.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: here is one problem: I am using the fact that the closed unit ball is compact, which is not true for an arbitrary metric space; editing to enforce $Y\subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Oh sorry. I almost nearly assumed that. Right, the unit ball is compact so that the function can be uniformly continuous.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: was also missing that $Y$ should be closed. See changes.

Comment: Why do you need $<\varepsilon/2$? I'm not following that. It appears to me that your argument should work with $<\varepsilon$ since the supremum in the final line is achieved at some point $x_0\in X$ so that you have $d((x_0,y),(x_0,y'))<\delta$ since $d(y,y')<\delta$. This looks correct to me, anyways!

Comment: @Nobody: you are correct! Thanks. I will incorporate your suggestion.

Comment: @user303911 I'm sorry,the closure was required. it's just  that  there are just certain assumptions that are blocking my mind every time I come into a question like this. I realize that a metric space could very well be open. I will have one final check and give a thumbs up.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: don't be sorry! I appreciate the extra pair of eyes :-)

Comment: Thank you, @user303911. This  time, I am cent per cent sure there is nothing wrong.

Comment: Does it allow $X$ to have two connected components?